# React getting access to properties of list component on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating my first app in React. It is a cinema booking app. I have component which is a single seat in screening room and a screening room component build with list of seats and reservation. I need access to seat id which user will choose and send this data to api after clicking on submit button. The way I am doing this now doesn't work. I think that because I do not render single seat in `screeningRoom` component but list.

Here is my code:

Seat component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./seat.css";

class Seat extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      bgc: this.props.ticket ? "red" : "grey",
      seatId: ""
    };
    //console.log(this.props)
  }
  reserve = () => {
    if (!this.props.ticket) {
      this.state.bgc === "grey"
        ? this.setState({ bgc: "green" })
        : this.setState({ bgc: "grey" });
    }
    this.setState({ seatId: this.props.id });
    //console.log (this.props.id)
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          className="seat"
          style={{ backgroundColor: this.state.bgc }}
          onClick={this.reserve}
        ></input>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Seat;
```

screeningRoom component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Seat from "./seats";
import "./screeningRoom.css";

export default class screeningRoom extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      seats: [],
      room: [],
      clicked: []
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ loading: true });

    const {
      match: { params }
    } = this.props;

    const res = await axios.get(
      `http://localhost:8080/api/shows/${params.id}/seats`
    );
    //console.log(res)

    this.setState({ seats: res.data.seats });
    //console.log(this.state.seats)
    this.setState({ room: res.data.name });
  }
  renderSeats() {
    return this.state.seats.map(seat => (
      <Seat
        onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
        key={seat._id}
        value={seat._id}
        ticket={seat.ticket}
        seat={seat}
      />
    ));
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target.value);
  }
  handleClick(e) {
    console.log(e.currentTarget.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className="screening-room d-flex flex-column justify-contnt-center align-items-center"
        style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
      >
        <h3 style={{ color: "white" }}>Room: {this.state.room} </h3>
        <div className="screen">screen</div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
          <div className={this.state.room}>{this.renderSeats()}</div>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Using event `target` is an inefficient way to handle data, you already know the value, just use it directly. [`onClick={() => this.handleClick(value)}`](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-pass-a-parameter-to-an-event-handler-or-callback)

Answer (score 2):

You aren't passing the `id` to the `Seat` component. So it makes sense why `this.props.id` is not there.

Either pass the id to the component:

```js
<Seat 
  id={seat._id} 
  onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} 
  key={seat._id} 
  value={seat._id} 
  ticket={seat.ticket} 
  seat={seat}
/>
```

Or change which prop you look for since they are the same:

```js
this.setState({seatId: this.props.value})
```

Here is a link to the [React docs on components and props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html). This is a very fundamental and important part of React and I would recommend starting here.

Comment: ok but how will I access that id? console does not log anything at the moment on click

Comment: Which log are you referring to? You have a function `handleClick` that gets bound to `this` twice, but then is never used. So I wouldn't expect that log to fire. In `reserve` the console log is commented out? I'm assuming you uncommented it? If so, and if you made my suggested change to pass `id`, it will be there

Comment: The console log in the constructor will also fail. You would need to log `props`, not `this.props`. And as a side note: you should also change the constructor to this `bgc: props.ticket ? "red" : "grey"`

Comment: click in Seat component works fine. Everything in this component work as it should. My problem is screeningRoom component. In Seat component user click on seat item and it changes color to green (as reserved). Then I want in screeningRoom component get chosen seat id from API and post it with submit button.

Comment: So then I think what you're wanting is to replace `setState({seatId: this.props.id })` with `this.props.onClick(this.props.id)`. then change `handleClick(id) {`

Comment: and how will I pass that state to screeningRoom component, where the submit button is?

Comment: You have a `clicked` array in that component's state. Maybe you'd like to store it there? `handleClick(id){ this.setState(prevState => ({clicked: [...prevState.clicked, id]})}`

Comment: Thank you so much Brian! "prevState" is exactly what I needed and did not know since now:)